# How to use local webfont in imported sass file?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, font-face

I created a react project using `create-react-app`, and am working with this folder structure:

- src/

  - Components/

    - Menu/

      - *Menu.scss*
  - Global/

    - fonts/

      - *myfont.ttf*
      - *etc...*
    - *myfont.scss*

In Menu.scss, I import using `@import '../../Global/myfont';`.

In myfont.scss, I include the font face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src: url('./fonts/myfont.ttf');
  ...
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style:  normal;
}
```

I get "Error: Module not found". 
If, for testing, I change the path to `src: url('../../Global/fonts/myfont.ttf');`, everything works.

Is there a way to set the URL path so it works regardless of where it is imported from?

Comment: If you already registered it on `myfont.scss` (assuming that's loaded in your webpack/other way), doesn't it work on `Menu.scss` if you just use `font-family: myfont;` ?

Comment: no, myfont isn't imported anywhere yet.. I import scss files in my .js module files, I don't fully understand how plain sass (_partials compiled into main css, and compiled css added to html) relates to sass as part of the react structure. this is my first test project :-)

Comment: If you're don't have a file bundler then each scss file you import from will have a different path since it's located in a different place in your project structure. If you have one scss that's loaded at `index.js` for instance, then all it can load other scss files that will use the rule i wrote above.

Comment: yes, you are right. haven't looked at the workings of the bundler yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you make a "base" scss file, where you write/import your fonts, icons, and other website-wide components, like header, footer etc. Then you import that base.scss file in each of your page's css.

base.scss:

```
$font-path: "../../Global/fonts" !default;
@font-face{
  src: url('#{$font-path}/myfont.ttf');
   ...
}
...
```

And in each page, add:

```
@import "base;
```

Comment: The way you wrote it would only help me if I was importing base.scss from a place two directories away from src. If I had an scss file in, say, Components/Menu/MenuButton, it would break again.

Comment: But if I could make it so that you'd have to specify the font-path wherever I include the global scss, hmm...

Comment: Depending where your base and font files will be, change the $font-path. For example, if base.scss is in Global folder, you should make it: $font-path: "./fonts" !default;